# Python: How does one recieve a random string, and display it into a label (tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.6

**Objective:** From a list of strings (set as variables), take one at random, and display it in a new  Tkinter window (assuming there is already one in the program). Also, how would one implement a class to run in a program? (It is different than the objective I am assuming.)

**Technical Information:**
Using Python Version 2.6.8 (for technical reasons) & Pycharm IDE (community version)

**Possible Solutions:** Use the randinit() command to get a random integer and depending on what the integer is, assign a string to a variable, which will then be display via the tkinter label's textvariable command.

**Conceptional Code for a Class:**

```
from Tkinter import *
import random

class popUp():
def __init__(self):
    top = self.top = Toplevel()
    self.nth = 0
    Label(top,text="Suggestion:").pack(side=TOP)
    self.message()
    Label(top,textvariable=self.inp)

def message(self):
    self.nth = random.randint(490, 500)
    if self.nth == 490:
        self.inp = "Have a turkey!"
    elif self.nth == 491:
        self.inp = "Have a turkey!"
    elif self.nth == 492:
        self.inp = "Have a turkey!"
    elif self.nth == 493:
        self.inp = "Have a turkey!"
    elif self.nth == 494:
        self.inp = "Have a turkey!"
    elif self.nth == 495:
        self.inp = "Have a turkey!"
    elif self.nth == 496:
        self.inp = "Have a turkey!"
    elif self.nth == 497:
        self.inp = "Have a turkey!"
    elif self.nth == 498:
        self.inp = "Have a turkey!"
    elif self.nth == 499:
        self.inp = "Have a turkey!"
    else:
        self.inp = "Have a turkey!"

   def main():

   root.mainloop()

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

**What I need:** Either a correction to conceptional code, different command I could use, or different code using the objectives listed.

Please comment if I am missing any essential information, and please respond thoroughly, but quickly.

**Please note** that my programming back-round is Very little, in Python and in general. Some concepts might have to be explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to choose a string at random is to put them all in a list, and then use `random.choice`. To change the text in the label, Tkinter gives you a Stringvar class that will keep the label up to date as its value changes. It looks like your `self.inp` might already be one (you seem to be missing `self.inp = Stringvar()` before you create the label), but you need to use its set method rather than reassign it. Putting them together looks like this:

```
def message(self):
   self.inp.set(random.choice(messages))
```

Where messages is set somewhere outside the class.

Comment: Can you have multiple stringvar()? I've already used two of them in the other part of my program.

Comment: @Rick_Roll: you can have as many as you want, but honestly, you don't need any. You can set and change the text of a label without using StringVars.

Comment: @BryanOakley  How would you do that?

Comment: @Rick_Roll: save a reference to the label (`self.label = Label(...)`) and then use configure (`self.label.configure(random.choice(messages))`)

Comment: Interesting... :) Thanks!